# Get multiples categories posts in admin post listing

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use the "pre_get_posts" action to change the posts query listing in the wordpress admin. What i want to achieve is display only posts with specific categories when a user have a certain role. For exemple, If the user have the 'Insider Editor' Role, he should be only allowed to edit posts that have specific categories so in the admin posts list i want to list only the posts they can edit.

It's kind of working, but i have 36 posts with the category "2" and only 1 post with he category "3"... and in the admin i just see 36 posts listed and they all have the category "2" even if the total items number is correctly displayed (37).

Here is my code

```
public function filter_post_for_xbox_insider_role($wp_query_obj)
{
    global $pagenow;

    if( !is_admin() ){
        return;
    }

    if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow )
    {
        return;
    }

    if( 'post' != $wp_query_obj->query['post_type'] )
    {
        return;
    }

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if($user->roles[0] != 'insider_editor')
    {
        return;
    }

    $wp_query_obj->set('cat', '2,3' );

}
```

Why is the `$wp_query_obj->set('cat', '2,3' );` not working properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an already a plugin that does what you need [Role Scoper](https://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/) in a tick of a box.

Comment: It's not a problem, User tables and roles are almost never gonna change or deprecate, so it's safe to use. I'd worry about SEO, amp, theme plugins